# How do I convert a double into an n-character string using exponential notation?

Tags: java, string, formatting, double

I have found this vise-versa many times on SO, but never like I want it.

I want to convert a double into a string that takes up *exactly* n characters.

If n is, for example, 6, then

1,000,123.456 would become 1.00E6

-1,000,123.456 would become 1.0E-6

1.2345678      would become 1.2345

1,000,000,000,000 would become 1.0E12

etc.

How do I achieve that?
Regards,
Claas M.

P.S How do I set tabs on SO?

Comment: Why 1.2345 and not (say) 1.23E0?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth OP wants 6 character

Comment: @Lrrr: The OP appears to want 6 *characters*...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sorry, fix that. And Understand what you said :)

Comment: 1.23E0 is also okay if formatting it to 1.2345 would be to complicated.

Comment: Am I missing something, but why is -1,000,123.456 = 1.0E-6?  I thought 1.0E-6 would equal 0.00001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're limiting you're exponential component to E0 to E99 (for positive exponential) and E0 to E-9 (for negative exponential), you could use a combination of DecimalFormat and Regex to format your results to be 6 characters in length.

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(1000123.456));         // would become 1.00E6 
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(-1123123.456));        // would become 1.1E-6 
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(1.2345678));           // would become 1.2345 
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(1000000000000L));      // would become 1.0E12
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(0.0000012345));        // would become 1.2E-6
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(0.0000000012345));     // would become 1.2E-9
    System.out.println(toSciNotation(12.12345E12));         // would become 1.2E13
}

private static String toSciNotation(double number) {
    return formatSciNotation(new DecimalFormat("0.00E0").format(number));
}

private static String toSciNotation(long number) {
    return formatSciNotation(new DecimalFormat("0.00E0").format(number));
}

private static String formatSciNotation(String strNumber) {
    if (strNumber.length() > 6) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+)(\\.\\d{2})(E-?\\d+)").matcher(strNumber);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            int diff = strNumber.length() - 6;
            strNumber = String.format("%s%s%s", 
                    matcher.group(1),
                    // We add one back to include the decimal point
                    matcher.group(2).substring(0, diff + 1),
                    matcher.group(3)); 
        }
    }
    return strNumber;
}
```

Results:

```
1.00E6
-1.1E6
1.23E0
1.0E12
1.2E-6
1.2E-9
1.2E13
```

Comment: Works really good, so thanks a lot!
I changed 
`return formatSciNotation(new DecimalFormat("0.00E0").format(number));`
to
`return formatSciNotation(new DecimalFormat(number<0?"0.0E0":"0.00E0").format(number));`
for both occurences so that negative numbers don't exceed the 6-digit Limit.
Also I think you wanted to write E9 instead of E99

Comment: Would be even more beautiful in a class that extends `java.text.Format`.